# The number of Gaussian primes

Tags: number-theory, gaussian-integers

Let $n$ be a natural number $\ge 2$.

Let $\pi(n)$ be the number of primes $(p)$ for $p\le n$ and $\pi g(n)$ the number of Gausian primes $(z = x + yi )$ for $|x|$ and $|y| \le n$.

Can the ratio $\pi g(n)/\pi(n)^2$ has a limit for $n \to \infty$?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify the problem to the more natural variant where the bounds defining $\pi g(n)$ are $x^2 + y^2 \le n^2$.  Since you mention $|x|,|y|$ I will assume you intend to include all conjugates of a given Gaussian prime in the count, but it's a distinction that doesn't make much difference to what follows.

Under this simplification, (let's call it) $\pi g'(n)$ is essentially $8$ times the number of primes congruent to $1 \pmod 4$ up to $n^2$, ignoring some insignificant terms: the $O(1)$ contribution from the prime $2$ and the $o(n)$ contribution from rational Gaussian primes like $7$.  The latter is asymptotic to $n^2/(4 \log n)$ by the Prime Number Theorem for arithmetic progressions, so $\pi g'(n) \sim 2n^2/\log n$.

$\pi(n)$ is of course, asymptotic to $n/\log n$.  So the ratio $\pi g'(n)/\pi(n)^2$ grows like $O(\log n)$ and thus it does not have a limit.  Since your square bounding region is even larger than the circle, the same divergence holds for $\pi g(n)$.

It would be more interesting to eliminate the $\log n$ factor by considering something like $\pi g(n)/(n \pi(n))$.  In that case I believe there are equidistribution results due to Hecke which would probably be enough to establish an asymptotic for the number of Gaussian primes inside the square bounding box (I expect it would be the same as the circle but scaled by a constant proportionate to the ratio of the areas, so $4/\pi$).

Comment: @ Erick Wong, the limit of ratio $\pi g’(n)/\pi (n)/n = 1.8 \sim 1.9$.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami No, the limit is $2$.  Just don't expect to be able to compute far enough to see something that large.  The sum of $1/p$ diverges, but it would take an inordinately long time to compute enough terms to add up to $6$.  Doesn't mean that it's convergent!

Comment: `@Erick Wong Is your result (2) the synthetically proved value?

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "synthetic", but yes it is provable.  I have already explained that $\pi g'(n)$ is asymptotic to $2 n^2 / \log n$, and $\pi(n)$ is asymptotic to $n / \log n$.  The calculation of $\pi g'(n) / \pi(n) / n \to 2$ is trivial from there.

Comment: @ Erick Wong I see. But the limiting tendency gives me a bit different value. My computation may be wrong.

Comment: @SeiichiKirikami If your computation only gives you approximately 1.8 or 1.9, how can you discern that from the theoretical limit of 2?  These quantities come with error terms of size $O(1/\log n)$, probably with a substantial constant.  So $n$ would have to be quite large to discern an error of 5%: what is your numerical evidence that the limit is $\le 1.9$?

Comment: @ Erick Wong I used the values of A091134 (OEIS). They give 2.5, 1.971, 1.867, 1.875 for n = 10, 100, 1000, 10000 respectively. n = 10^5 may give the value nearer to 2. Regrettably, Mathematica produces “ no memory available” message for it.

Comment: It's understandable how you could get that impression from this data but it is admittedly quite sparse.  Here's a graph of the Li-approximation to $\pi(n)$ which accounts for some of the $O(1/\log n)$ errors: goo.gl/jjisPt  We do get an early spike from this term, but at the small scale of $n \le 100$ there are lower-order error terms of size $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{n})$ that are still very relevant, and those are missing from this graph.

Comment: So that's not to say that the trend line from 1000 to 10000 is necessarily credible, but it means that we should ignore the first two data points 10 and 100.  The correct conclusion from that numerical data is probably just that it isn't enough to conclude much about the limit.  Extending the above graph to 100000 suggests it may not be far enough to witness the ratio going above $1.9$.  As I said, these asymptotics are very hard to witness by direct computation.  For example see the discussion at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem#Numerical_examples